# Strange behavior from uint32_t, acting like signed int (Nano clone)

Tags: arduino-nano, printf

I'm having trouble with these variables. As you can see they're uint32_t type, so they should have a maximum value of 4 million or so, but they're rolling over and going negative at 32,767 like a signed int. Here's the relevant code:

```
byte lPin = 7;
char buff[100];
uint32_t loAvg = 0;
uint32_t hiAvg = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(lPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(lPin, HIGH); // Active LOW, so this is off

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Generate high/low averages
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    loAvg += analogRead(A0);
  }
  loAvg /= 100;

  digitalWrite(lPin, LOW);
  delay(500);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    hiAvg += analogRead(A0);
  }
  hiAvg /= 100;
  
  digitalWrite(lPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  
  sprintf(buff, "loAvg=%d, hiAvg=%d", loAvg, hiAvg);
  Serial.println(buff);

  Serial.println(hiAvg);
  digitalWrite(lPin, LOW);
  hiAvg = 0;
}

void loop() {
  sprintf(buff, "test=%d", hiAvg);
  Serial.println(buff);
  hiAvg+=100;
}
```

I removed a bunch of stuff from the code to save posting the whole (much longer) thing. If it ends up being relevant I can though, I just think I narrowed the problem down to this. Observing the serial monitor I get this on startup:

```
loAvg=287, hiAvg=0
933
test=0
test=100
test=200
...
```

The `test=#` repeats until 32700, then continues at -32736. I'm confused by the hiAvg=0 followed by the 933, showing that it totally is getting a high average, because that's around what it should be. Even if it's the sprintf() messing with it, in the setup function the value should only be around the 900 range so it wouldn't overflow there. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: there are only three lines involved ... my bet is on sprintf() ... specifically the %d ... that formats the data for output

Comment: `"%" PRIu32`  There's almost no reason to use `sprintf` over `snprintf`. In this code as written, no reason to use either.

Comment: This code above is only the parts that were relevant to the question so I can understand not seeing the point. The `sprintf` is only used during testing. When DEBUG is defined, the serial prints are between #ifdef / #endif blocks so they're not present during normal operation. I did end up figuring out that I needed %lu. Thank you for the replies and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%d` expects a signed int. `%u` expects an unsigned int. Insert the `l` modifier to expect a long in each of those cases. So you need a format code of `%lu` to print a uint32_t.

The following code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
{
    uint32_t x=110000;
    char buf[50];

   // Open console
   Serial.begin(115200);
   
    sprintf(buf, "%%d: %d\n", x);       Serial.print(buf);
    sprintf(buf, "%%u: %u\n", x);       Serial.print(buf);
    sprintf(buf, "%%ld: %ld\n", x); Serial.print(buf);
    sprintf(buf, "%%lu: %lu\n", x); Serial.print(buf);
}


void loop() {
   ;
}
```

prints this:

```
%d: -21072
%u: 44464
%ld: 110000
%lu: 110000
```

Answer (score 2):

### *`printf` and bit-width specified types

`#include <inttypes.h>` or C++'s `#include <cinttypes>` counterpart (when you have it; not on AVR-based Arduinos) gives access to macros defined for the format specifiers for each of the fixed, fast, and least versions of these types.  All of these macros expand to some string literal or another.

For `uint32_t` the macro defining to its format specifier is `PRIu32`.  For an AVR, this is `"%lu"`.  It needn't be `"%lu"` in  the general case.  `uint32_t` is one of the types where you can often get away with using `"%lu"` and have it either work out being exactly correct for the platform or somewhat incorrect but working anyway because it's a platform where `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` happen to have the same representation.

In C and C++, and so Arduino, adjacent string literals are concatenated into one logical string in the early phases of compilation that follow the macro preprocessor.  So, the intention is that you choose the correct macro and you put them following something like `"%"` or `"%12"` if you wanted a minimum-width of 12.  As in `"%" PRIu32` and `"%12" PRIu32` respectively.  So, in your case,  having included (directly or indirectly) `<stdint.h>` for `uint32_t` and `<inttypes.h>` for `PRIu32` or their C++ counterpart headers, and then your code looks something like:

```cpp
snprintf(
  buf,
  sizeof buf,
  "loAvg=%" PRIu32 ", hiAvg=%" PRIu32,
  loAvg,
  hiAvg
);
```

There's little to no reason to not use the s**n**printf.  The reason why the non-n version exists at all is mostly that `snprintf` showed up in 1999, instead of circa the mid 1970s.  I'd say it's pretty safe to use `snprintf` now.  There probably hasn't been an Arduino that doesn't support it.  About the only reason to use `sprintf` would be if you were calling it with a null pointer for the buffer argument to get it to do a dry run and tell how much memory you need for the result, and you just didn't want to supply a limiting size.

There are `PRI...` [macros for all of the combinations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) of standard bit width and choice of signed decimal, unsigned decimal, lowercase hex, uppercase hex, etc.  E.g `"%" "PRId16"` is  for `int16_t` in decimal, `"%" PRIX64` for `uint64_t` in hexadecimal with uppercase alphabetics.  The are ones for the `fast` and `least` bitwidth types, and whole show is repeated with macros starting with `SCN` for the `scanf` specifiers, not that you should use the `scanf` family functions for anything really.

`snprintf` and `sprintf` are variadic functions.  After the format specifier there's no type information available to the compiler to know what conversions to apply.  It will convert types smaller than `int` rank up to `int` on `unsigned int`, but that's about it.  E.g. it will not reliably down-convert an `unsigned long long` into an `unsigned int`, the way it would if the types were known.  Modern compilers will sometimes warn you if you grossly misapply format specifiers, but they're not required to.  They're not expected to dissect the format string and attempt to recover type information.  So it's up to you to make sure whatever you pass in for arguments matches with the format specifiers.  As you've seen it's confusing if you get it wrong with `printf`-type functions, but it doesn't cause real problems unless you, you know, don't limit it to stay within the output buffer with the s**n**printf version.  In the case of passing in an `unsigned long long` where an `unsigned int` was expected, in practice, for a little-endian system like AVR, it may appear to do that for one argument.  But then it may fail on the next argument, because the size of the last argument was in correct, it is now reading from the wrong place.

### `Print`/`Stream`/`Serial` concatenating and buffering

The way you're using `sprintf` in your code isn't taking advantage of any of its features that `Serial`/`Print` doesn't do.

```cpp
Serial.print(F("loAvg="));
Serial.print(loAvg);
Serial.print(F(", hiAvg="));
Serial.println(hiAvg);
```

Despite taking four lines, this is actually smaller, faster, more reliable code than the `sprintf` one-liner.

Putting the output into a buffer first might make sense if you were going to put it into a packet, like for UDP or nRF24L01.  But, `Print`/`Stream`/`Serial` already concatenates and buffers things for you.

---

Incidentally, if you're going to use `printf` functions and you're doing it on an AVR-based Arduino, look at the avr-libc [documentation for the `_P` variants](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html) that take their format strings from PROGMEM and the [`PSTR` macro](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga05ca900ebf7cd121be73c654d9ccb3eb).

It is also possible to complete the implementation of `<stdio.h>` for `stdout` and `stderr` through libc-specific means.  So, if you really want to, you can have the regular `printf` function pushing data out through `Serial` (among other things) such that you *don't* need to buffer repeatedly with `sprintf`.